# Error to access a .xls file in android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I've a file named "question.xls". I'm trying to generate a two dimensional string array with that [sheet](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E-wCPGFMkWGkJJhgwu00Nm-b7JlfZoHz).I've add the jxl.jar as resource library.Here's my code and problem.Here's the MainActivity.java.I've just tried to acces each cell then assigning them into two dimensional array

```
package com.example.bhagyo.excell;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] str;
    String zz;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        readQuestion();
    }
    private void readQuestion() {
        try{
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("question.xls");
            Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
            int k=0;
            int row = sheet.getRows();
            int col = sheet.getColumns();
            Log.d("Result","table details: "+row+"  "+col);
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j,i);
                    zz="";
                    if(j==5){
                        zz=zz+"Answer: "+(cell.getContents()).toString();
                    }
                    else if(j==0){
                        zz=(cell.getContents()).toString()+" ";
                    }
                    else{
                        zz=zz+" "+(cell.getContents()).toString();
                    }
                }
                str[k++]=zz;
                Log.d("MyActivity","Dekhi "+zz);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My verbose log is full of empty the error is mainly caused bu null array but where is it

```
10-27 15:29:50.631 2719-2719/? D/Result: table details: 970  7
10-27 15:29:50.632 2719-2719/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-27 15:29:50.633 2719-2719/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bhagyo.excell, PID: 2719
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bhagyo.excell/com.example.bhagyo.excell.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
        at com.example.bhagyo.excell.MainActivity.readQuestion(MainActivity.java:55)
        at com.example.bhagyo.excell.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `str` array. Initialize it after you define `row`:

```
int row = sheet.getRows();
str = new String[row];
```

That will get rid of the NullPointerException.

However, you're not creating a 2-dimensional array, either. You're creating a single-dimensional array with each index holding a single string containing the data of the last column only.

Change your code a bit:

Change

```
String[] str;
```

To

```
String[][] str;
```

Initialize it after initializing `row` and `col`:

```
int row = sheet.getRows();
int col = sheet.getColumns();
str = new String[row][col];
```

Then change your loops a bit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j,i);
        String column;
        if (j == 5) {
            column = "Answer: " + cell.getContents();
        } else {
            column = cell.getContents().toString();
        }

        str[i][j] = column;
    }
}
```